# Datatable sort by date correctly

Tags: javascript, jquery, django, datatables

I'm using `Django framework` for my web site but to show info I use the plugin `Datatable` so one column show date info, the format that is used to show the date is like `May. 6, 2017` so when I sort the date column take the order as string and not date so the first date to show is like `August 10, 2017` **Is there a way to sort by date using that format?**

Comment: Show some code where you need this. How you are using datatable. It will be really hard to understand without any code that what exactly is your requirement

Comment: You could use the data-order tag in that column.

Comment: This is an example @ArpitSolanki https://jsfiddle.net/dunhxf5m/

Answer (score 1):

When defining the columns of your DataTable, you need to specify the `render` callback as in the example below:

```
        columns: [
            {
                title: "Date",
                data: "yourDateRef",
                render: function(data, type, row) {
                    if (type == "display") {
                        return prettyFormat(data);
                    }
                    else {
                        return data;
                    }
                }
            },
            ...
```

Basically, DataTables calls the render callback to display the data (`type=="display"`), but also when the data needs to be sorted (`type=="sort"`), or filtered (`type=="filter"`).

This allows you to control how a given field is displayed, but also sorted and filtered.

More information: https://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.render

Hope this helps!